# unable to connect to firebase realtime database andriod studio

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am having some trouble connecting to firebase's realtime database.

I am getting this error:
[image: compilation error]

even though my database url I am referencing is correct. This is my code:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReferenceFromUrl("https://i021task-b5626-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/");
```

and i got the URL from this:

[image: database]

Can someone please help me figure out why this is? I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the database URL to the `instance` call:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://i021task-b5626-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/");
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
```

Also see: [How to change firebase URL for FirebaseReference in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69429885/how-to-change-firebase-url-for-firebasereference-in-android-studio/69429924#69429924) and [React native firebase realtime database reference return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69675249/react-native-firebase-realtime-database-reference-return-null/69678318#69678318)