# Call all values of a specific sub-child in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my firebase realtime database
[image]

I am trying to call all values of "Deadline" but I can't make it work.

I tried

```
DatabaseReference databaseDeadline = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("subjects");
DatabaseReference databaseDeadline1 = databaseDeadline.child("MMW");
```

and

```
DatabaseReference databaseDeadline = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("subjects");
DatabaseReference databaseDeadline1 = databaseDeadline.child("MMW");
DatabaseReference databaseDeadline2 = databaseDeadline1.child("");
```

and

```
DatabaseReference databaseDeadline = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("subjects").child("MMW");
```

and

```
DatabaseReference databaseDeadline = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("subjects").child("MMW").child("");
```

then I test here to see if it works but it always return null no matter what. How can i make it work? Thank you in advance

```
*db_reference*.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                String dbDeadline = snapshot.child("Deadline").getValue(String.class);
                if (dbDeadline != null){
                    Toast.makeText(AssignmentListMmw.this, "I exist",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(AssignmentListMmw.this, "XXX",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the value from `subjects/MMW/B/Deadline`, you'd do:

```
DatabaseReference db_reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("subjects/MMW/B/Deadline");
db_reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        String dbDeadline = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
        System.out.println(dbDeadline);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); // Never ignore errors
    }
});
```

If neither your `onDataChange` nor the `onCancelled` is getting called, you may not be connected to the database correctly. In that case, consider redownloading your `google-services.json` or specifying the database URL in the call to `getInstance(...)` as shown here: [unable to connect to firebase realtime database andriod studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71286828).

---

If you want to read all `Deadline` values under `subjects/MMW`, you can do:

```
DatabaseReference db_reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("subjects/MMW");
db_reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            String dbDeadline = child.child("Deadline").getValue(String.class);
            System.out.println(dbDeadline);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); // Never ignore errors
    }
});
```

Comment: But what if I want to call all the values of "Description" under MMW?

Comment: I added an example for that too. Going forward, please be clear about such requirements in your question.